# We need a way to redirect user back to our application on successful change password on azure

Tags: azure, active-directory

In our website, we are displaying a change password link which redirects user to "https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/ChangePassword.aspx", where user will be able to change the password.

On successful change password, we need a way to redirect user back to our application. Currently it is redirecting user to "https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/profile/default.aspx".

Any help or hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behaviour and currently this is not possible. There is already a similar feature request on feedback.azure.com where you can suggest new features, enhancements or bugs.

If you would love to see this feature you can upvote this feature -> http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/7156218-redirect-new-users-to-application-not-manage-wind

My experience is that they are actively looking at these features and also implement them (when enough users request them).